# How to call a simple Objective-C function from Javascript

Tags: javascript, objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to call an Objective-C method from Javascript in a Cocoa/WebKit app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92471/how-to-call-an-objective-c-method-from-javascript-in-a-cocoa-webkit-app)

How to call a simple Objective- C function from Javascript.
Say I have a function :

> -(void) callFromJavascript {
>   // How to call this method of Objective -C from a Javascript function.

}

Comment: check this link u will get your answer http://blog.techno-barje.fr/post/2010/10/06/UIWebView-secrets-part3-How-to-properly-call-ObjectiveC-from-Javascript/

Comment: The answer I used was here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2293305/105539 In my comments below it, I showed how to do it even easier.

Answer (score 0):

One mechanism is to intercept `document.location` changes (and cancel them) and call your method when the requested change to `document.location` matches a URL you predefined.

Then from JS you just change `document.location` to that predefined URL.

To intercept the changes override:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)_webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType;
```

and return NO when `request` matches what you're setting in JS as `document.location`.

Comment: See Samarth Pandey's answer. It's a better approach.