# Calling Objective-C methods from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, iphone, objective-c

From [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/SafariJSProgTopics/Tasks/ObjCFromJavaScript.html), it seems to be possible except for the sentence highlighted :

> The web scripting capabilities of WebKit permit you to access
>   Objective-C properties and call Objective-C methods from the
>   JavaScript scripting environment.
>
> An important but not necessarily obvious fact about this bridge is
>   that **it does not allow any JavaScript script to access Objective-C**.
>   You cannot access Objective-C properties and methods from a web
>   browser unless a custom plug-in has been installed. The bridge is
>   intended for people using custom plug-ins and JavaScript environments
>   enclosed within WebKit objects (for example, a WebView).

Or should I consider the solution from Sixten Otto shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1662473/how-to-call-objective-c-from-javascript) ?
What I wish to do is : when user tap on an image in UIWebView a JavaScript routine calls a method in Objective-C.

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7171163/how-do-i-call-an-objective-c-method-from-javascript-on-uiwebview?rq=1

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1662473/how-to-call-objective-c-from-javascript

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to call an Objective-C method from Javascript in a Cocoa/WebKit app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92471/how-to-call-an-objective-c-method-from-javascript-in-a-cocoa-webkit-app)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you see this [JavaScriptFromObjC](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DisplayWebContent/Tasks/JavaScriptFromObjC.html)

and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1662473/how-to-call-objective-c-from-javascript)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, I saw those.  But I am hoping for a more proper way instead of workarounds like using a URL.

Comment: URL schemes are not a 'workaround,' they are the only official Apple sanctioned way of doing this type of communication.

Comment: Owen and Lithu, I think you are right.  After spending exceedingly more time on this topic than I'd expected, it becomes apparent that there wouldn't be any formal API for this type of communication.  The likely reason is there had been a trade off between security and flexibility.  It would be quite a security concern if some downloaded code from the web can freely call any local methods on the device.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at open source project [Apache Cordova](http://cordova.apache.org/). You'll learn how to interact with native code for other mobile platforms, too.

Comment: I took a look at your link.  It's surely worth looking into even though I am not thinking of using it at least for the moment.