# How to call a objective c code from javascript in cocoa

Tags: javascript, cocoa, javascriptcore

Right now my javascript looks like this :

```
 testStackData.addOrUpdateHeader("username", "vikas test", 1);
 testStackData.addOrUpdateHeader("testHeader", testStackData.priorResults.responseBody.cars[0].name, 1);
 testStackData.addOrUpdateVariable("carNameTest", "variable updated from pre script", 1);
 testStackData.stepError.haveError = false;
 return testStackData
```

Now I need to create an Objective-C function `addOrUpdateHeader` or `addOrUpdateVariable` as mentioned in javascript.

But I am confused as how to call these functions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to call an Objective-C method from Javascript in a Cocoa/WebKit app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92471/how-to-call-an-objective-c-method-from-javascript-in-a-cocoa-webkit-app)

Comment: They are using webview to achieve this but my requirement doesnot allow me to use webview.  I was looking something using Javascriptcore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got my javascript code running my application with the help of Javascript core framework.

I created json string with my javascript functions embedded in the string itself. As javascript is lose in its definitions, it allowed the calling and execution of the functions effectively.

Moving on to the code, I created separate function for **addOrUpdateHeader**
**addOrUpdateVariable**

The functions read as follows :

```
"addOrUpdateHeader" : 



   function(headerName, headerValue, trackHistory){
        if(this.projectServers.projectServerDefaultHeaders.length>0) {
        var index ;
        var isHeaderNameExists = false;
        for(var h =0; h<this.projectServers.projectServerDefaultHeaders.length;h++) {
        if(this.projectServers.projectServerDefaultHeaders[h].headerName === headerName) {
        index=h;
        isHeaderNameExists = true;
        break;
        } }
        if(isHeaderNameExists) {
       this.projectServers.projectServerDefaultHeaders[index].headerValue = headerValue;
        }
        else {
        this.projectServers.projectServerDefaultHeaders.push({
        headerName : headerName,
        headerValue : headerValue,
        projectServerDefaultHeaderId : '',
        trackHistory : trackHistory
        });
        } } },
        "addOrUpdateVariable" : function(variableName, variableValue){
        if(this.projectServers.projectServerDefaultVariables.length>0) {
        var index ;
        var isVariableNameExists = false;
        for(var v =0; v<this.projectServers.projectServerDefaultVariables.length;v++) {
        if(this.projectServers.projectServerDefaultVariables[v].variableName === variableName) {
        index=v;
        isVariableNameExists = true;
        break;
        } }
        if(isVariableNameExists) {
 this.projectServers.projectServerDefaultVariables[index].variableValue = variableValue;
        }
        else {
        this.projectServers.projectServerDefaultVariables.push({
        variableName : variableName,
        variableValue : variableValue,
        projectServerDefaultVariableId : ''
        });
        }}
        }
```

and then used javascript core framework's JSContext to do the required functionality with the help of following code

```
JSContext *context = [[JSContext alloc] init];
    context.exceptionHandler = ^(JSContext *context, JSValue *exception) {
        NSLog(@"[%@:%@:%@] %@\n%@", exception[@"sourceURL"], exception[@"line"], exception[@"column"], exception, [exception[@"stack"] toObject]);
    };
    [context evaluateScript:testStackData];
    NSString * jsCode = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"var prescript = function (testStackData) {%@}",script];
    [context evaluateScript:jsCode];
    JSValue * ret = [context evaluateScript:@"prescript(testStackData);"];
```

here  testStackData is my json string